# How to remove spaces and special characters from string?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a function that returns true if a character is a form of punctuation and I'm trying to write another function that accepts a string and removes the spaces and punctuation marks while calling the first function. I got most of it I think. But now I'm stuck. Any help is appreciated.

```
var isPunct = function(ch) {

    if (ch = ch.match(/[,.!?;:'-]/g))
        return true
    else
        return false
}

//B

var compress = function(s) {
    var result = "";

    //loop to traverse s
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        if (!(isPunct(ch));
            //(isPunct(s.charAt(i) || s.charAt(i) == " "));
            //do nothing
            else
                result = result + !compress(i)
        }

        return result
    }
```

Comment: What is expected result of `if (ch = ch.match(/[,.!?;:'-]/g))`?

Comment: `if (!(isPunct(ch));` Where is `ch` defined? It also appears you can reduce your entire `isPunct` function to a `return ch.match(/[,.!?;:'-]/g)`.

Comment: This calls for a `replace` with regular expression: `compress = s => s.replace(/[,.!?;:'-]/g, '')`

Comment: the isPunct function works on its own as is. So I'm not worried about that. I'm just trying to get my if statement mainly.

Comment: Trincot, is there a way I can call the isPunct function in the replace regex instead of retyping the regex?

Comment: Yes, see my answer (near the end of it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues:

- The inner condition should in fact be the opposite: you want to do nothing when it *is* a punctuation character, i.e. you *don't* want to add it to the result. Only in the other case you want to do that.
- The call `!compress(i)` is wrong: first of all that function expects a string, not an index, and it returns a string, not a boolean (so to perform `!` on it). It seems like you want to call your function recursively, and although that is an option, you are *also* iterating over the string. You should do one of the two: recursion or iteration.
- You reference a variable `ch` in the `compress` function which you have not defined there.

So, if you want to write `compress` the *iteration* way, change your code as follows:

```
var compress = function(s) {
    var result = "", ch; // define ch.

    //loop to traverse s
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        ch = s[i]; // initialise ch.
        if (!isPunct(ch)) result = result + ch; // only add when not punctuation
    }
    return result;
}
```

If on the other hand you want to keep your recursive call to `compress`, then you should do away with your `for` loop:

```
var compress = function(s) {
    var result = "", ch, rest;

    if (s.length == 0) return '';
    result = compress(s.substr(1)); // recursive call
    ch = s[0];
    if (!isPunct(ch)) result = ch + result;
    return result;
}
```

The function `isPunct` also has a strange thing happening: it assigns a boolean value to `ch` in the `if` expression. This does not make your function malfunction, but that assignment serves no purpose: the `match` method already returns the boolean you need for your `if` condition.

It is also not really nice-looking to first evaluate a boolean expression in an `if` to then return that same value in the form of `false` and `true`. This you can do by just returning the evaluated expression itself:

```
var isPunct = function(ch) {
    return ch.match(/[,.!?;:'-]/g);
}
```

On a final note, you don't really need the `isPunct` function if you only use it in `compress`. The whole logic can be performed in one function only, like this:

```js
let compress = s => s.replace(/[,.!?;:'-]/g,'');
// Demo:  
console.log(compress('a,b,c')); // abc
```

If you prefer to keep `isPunct` and don't want to repeat the regular expression elsewhere, then you can do the replace like this:

```js
let isPunct = ch => ch.match(/[,.!?;:'-]/g);

let compress = s => Array.from(s).filter(ch => !isPunct(ch)).join('');
// Demo:  
console.log(compress('a,b,c')); // abc
```

Note how the use of ES6 arrow functions and ES5 Array methods makes the code quite lean.

Comment: Awesome man. Thank you so much. I got it all now. Added a regex to replace the white spaces in the string. Thanks a ton man

Comment: Note that [arrow functions (`=>`) aren't available in IE](http://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions).

Comment: IE? What is that? :-)